# Why does this function take up a lot of memory overtime

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why does this small function after `a` reaches around almost 200,000 under about:memory tab it says that the devtools's total memory is: 1079408k? can someone explain why?

```
var a = 0;
(function loop(){
 a++;
 console.count();
 call = setTimeout(loop);
})()
```

Comment: Because it's infinite recursion.

Comment: Could it be because there's 200k setTimeouts?

Comment: Because you never stop calling `loop`?

Comment: these are all bad things.

Comment: I know that I never stop but, why does it reach that much memory. I can stop it by calling `clearTimeout(call)`. But I'm trying to understand if I'm not filling up the callstack by using `setTimeout` and I'm only using 1 variable a. Unless it's the call variable?

Comment: There's also a lot of lines in the console, no ?

Comment: true? could it be that only? meaning let's say I don't call `console.count` would there be a point where the memory doesn't grow or say stays around the same range?

Comment: even when I clear the console and check about:memory page again it's still around 500,000

Comment: @Edwin and without dev tools ?

Comment: the page's memory itself does not grow but under about:memory there's a devtool page which's memory is growing

Comment: and now I have to wait again till `a == 200000` because I had two fingers on my trackpad and ended up closing my browser

Comment: @Edwin You don't have to wait, just look at the task manager while it runs.

Comment: @dystroy huh? i'm saying so the memory can go back up again

Comment: anybody else got anything?

Comment: @Todd can you elaborate a bit more on what's bad and what's good?

Comment: I think that was my point initially -- that I couldn't add too much further than what had been covered in the first few comments. Interesting question! Even though infinite recursion is crystal to most of us, to try and articulate the process and its dangers (for someone who may not have it so clear) is an interesting challenge.

Comment: I've been working on some code that goes through about a million or more combinations. and I was wondering why it's slowing down and taking up memory so I just wrote that small code and tested if even this takes up lots of memory. Now I'm trying to find out why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was speculation in comments but nobody checked, so [I did it](http://jsbin.com/jojidawami/1/edit) :

When you remove the `console.count()`, the memory stops growing. What you saw was just the console growing : those lines must be stored somewhere.

Comment: didn't even get notified about this answer. But I also mentioned that even when I cleared the console, for some reason the memory was still up to 500,000k

Comment: Ok I see that, the `console.count()` takes up a lot of memory, also I've tried changing the first line from `var a = 0;` to `var a = 0, call;` I believe that had something to do with it as well thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function itself continues on infinitely in a loop.

```
call = setTimeout(loop);
```

Just calls the function again, which calls that line again. There is no return statement, so the recursion never stops and it loops on infinitely.

As pointed out in the comments, it isn't necessarily recursive since there is no stack building up. The memory is building up because as dystroy pointed out

```
console.count();
```

causes the console to count the amount of times that function is called, and since it is being called infinitely, the memory is quickly filled with thousands of lines `console.count()` output.

Comment: It's not really a recursion. There's no growing stack per se, unless it's added by some dev tools.

Comment: But it is recursion in a sense, since setTimeout calls the function which then calls setTimeout that then calls the function, etc.

Comment: And why would that consume memory ?

Comment: setTimeout defer the call, it's not executed in the same 'scope'

Comment: the variable `call` has to be kept track of in addition to `a`

Comment: @Wold—they're both global, and setTimeout is just passed a reference.

Comment: It's always the same variable, changing its value 200000 times doesn't make the memory grow.

Comment: that's what I'm saying changing the variable value shouldn't grow the memory