# Why does this function take up a lot of memory overtime [part 2]

Tags: javascript

This is sort of a continuation to my other question: [Why does this function take up a lot of memory overtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828688/why-does-this-function-take-up-a-lot-of-memory-overtime)

Yet a couple of hours ago I realize that my actual code (which is not the following) took up the same amount of memory as the following code with `a.length` being greater than **4 million** in my actual code, after perhaps 12 hours of running, Then it crashed.

```
var a = [];
(function loop(){
    a.push([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]);
    if(a.length > 4e6) clearTimeout(call);
    call = setTimeout(loop);
})();
```

As you can see I call `clearTimeout(call);` after the length of `a` is greater than **4 million.** Why when `a.length > 1000000` the blank tab which I run the above code takes about 1,000,000k+ in memory.

P.S:

- The objects in my actual code are not empty and have data.
- In my other question the memory was being fulled up on the developer tool. This time it's fulling up the page itself?

Comment: Are you sure you want `push` and not `concat` ? Do you really want to build an array of arrays ? In any case without knowing what are the real objects we can't estimate if what you see is normal or not...

Comment: @dystroy Hello again you were part of the other question.

Yes my code is generating combinations. So I have an array of arrays of combinations.

Comment: Is your question about why the loop doesn't stop ? If so, Bergi answered.

Comment: No I don't want it to stop until `a.length > 4e6`. Until I have all my combinations. I only put `> 4e6` because that's when my program crashed so I wanted to see how much the array can take. Then I see that this happened even with empty objects.

Comment: I don't know what's in your array but an array of 4 million arrays **is** big. You don't usually handle that in memory when you can do otherwise.

Comment: "when you can do otherwise" what do you mean? Well my code before it crashed went through 11 million+ yet only 4 million met the criteria for me to push it to the array holding those arrays.

Comment: I mean you normally devise an algorithm so that it doesn't involve such a storage.

Comment: Please don't make edits to your question which invalidates all answers given. If an answer solved this particular question, accept it, and ask another one (linking to this one, and explaining the differences)

Comment: @SecondRikudo My question wasn't answered. I didn't ask how to stop it. I asked why is so much memory is being consumed.

Comment: @dystroy
My combinations are based on daily stats. There's been days where I've only got around 3000 combinations. And all are completely different the same for the 4 million all are completely different. It is correct for me to get **4 million** combinations.

Comment: Try multiply the size of the thing you store by 36000000 (4 million arrays with 9 items in each) before you get all surprised about the memory use.

Comment: @Chewie
What multiply how?

I wanna know is it really that 4 million arrays is what taking up the memory because in my actual code that took 12 hours to crash and reach 1million K in memory. The above code only took about an hour to reach the same memory with empty objects compared to my actual code with objects with data in it?

Comment: Well first you need to find out what your object fills, you can either do rough head-math style and just add 24bytes (afaik that is the size of an empty Java object + 1 reference to it) to the size of the data you store. Or you can make 1 object and measure the memory use (lots of posts about how to do that around the internet).

Answer (score 1):

That `clearTimeout` is not effective. `call` will hold the id of the last `setTimeout` call, i.e. for the `loop` run that is currently executing. Clearing it does not do anything, and you will schedule a new run of `loop` in every case. You would need to do

```
var call = setTimeout(loop);
if (a.length >= 4e6) clearTimeout(call);
```

but better go with the standard

```
var a = [];
(function loop(){
    a.push([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]);
    if (a.length < 4e6)
        setTimeout(loop);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks I see where my mistake was. But now I have to run this and see if it takes up memory. In my actual code it's fine it does stop correctly. Yet my question is why is it taking up so much memory. Is it that I have an array with 3 million arrays in it?

Comment: Of course 4 million arrays, each with 9 empty yet distinct objects, will take up a huge chunk of memory…

Comment: I'm wondering why in about an hour of running the above code did it reach  1 million K in memory. However on my actual code which I'm doing the same. But with objects that actually are not empty 12 hours later it reached 1 million K with more 4 million arrays in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a.length > 4e6) clearTimeout(call);
call = setTimeout(loop);
```

this does absolutely nothing.

```
if(a.length <= 4e6) call = setTimeout(loop);
```

this would be the line to terminate the loop.